# Methods signatures in a parent class that don't have to be overriden?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a parent class that contains two methods of the same name that take different parameters:

```
protected abstract void FilterByLetter(char a);

protected abstract void FilterByLetter(char a, char b);
```

In practice, only one of these will need to be used in each class that inherit from it. Is there a way to allow one to be overridden without the other?

Comment: Annotate other class as `Sealed` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two new abstract base classes that override just one of the methods and inherit the children from them:

```
public abstract class A : OriginalBaseClass
{
    protected override void FilterByLetter(char a)
    {
        // Don't do anything
    }
}

public abstract class B : OriginalBaseClass
{
    protected override void FilterByLetter(char a, char b)
    {
        // Don't do anything
    }
}

public class ClassThatNeedsOnlyTwoParameterOverload : A
{
    protected override void FilterByLetter(char a, char b)
    {
        // Add necessary code
    }
}

public class ClassThatNeedsOnlyOneParameterOverload : B
{
    protected override void FilterByLetter(char a)
    {
        // Add necessary code
    }
}
```